# Opencart SQL error in your SQL syntax Error No. 1064

Tags: php, sql, opencart

I am using the following query to select data from an Opencart DB.  It all work fine until the final join where I am linking the product_to_category table, I then get the 1064 error.  Without that join the query work fine - can anyone help please?

```
$purchased = "SELECT op.quantity, oo.product_option_value_id, oo.product_option_id,     op.order_product_id,op.product_id,op.name,o.order_id,ptc.product_id
                    FROM `order` o
                    JOIN `order_product` op ON o.order_id = op.order_id
                    LEFT JOIN `order_option` oo ON op.order_product_id =  oo.order_product_id
                    LEFT JOIN 'product_to_category' ptc ON  op.product_id = ptc.product_id";    

    if (!empty($data['filter_date_start'])) {
        $purchased .= " WHERE DATE(o.date_added) >= '" . $this->db- >escape($data['filter_date_start']) . "'";
    }   else {
        $purchased .= " WHERE DATE(o.date_added) >= '1900-01-01'";
    }
    if (!empty($data['filter_date_end'])) {
        $purchased .= " AND DATE(o.date_added) <= '" . $this->db->escape($data['filter_date_end']) . "'";
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the single quotes around the last table name as below:

```
 $purchased = "SELECT op.quantity, oo.product_option_value_id, oo.product_option_id,     op.order_product_id,op.product_id,op.name,o.order_id,ptc.product_id
                FROM `order` o
                JOIN `order_product` op ON o.order_id = op.order_id
                LEFT JOIN `order_option` oo ON op.order_product_id =  oo.order_product_id
                LEFT JOIN `product_to_category` ptc ON  op.product_id = ptc.product_id";    

if (!empty($data['filter_date_start'])) {
    $purchased .= " WHERE DATE(o.date_added) >= '" . $this->db- >escape($data['filter_date_start']) . "'";
}   else {
    $purchased .= " WHERE DATE(o.date_added) >= '1900-01-01'";
}
if (!empty($data['filter_date_end'])) {
    $purchased .= " AND DATE(o.date_added) <= '" . $this->db->escape($data['filter_date_end']) . "'";
}
```

Have a nice day!!